# Possible to make a:after/before pseudo elements clickable as part of the link?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

pseudo elements a:after a:before allow you to add text that appears to be part of the link. However, I can't seem to figure out a way to make that portion clickable as part of the link.

For example the following css shows the url afterward:

```
  a:after {
     content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }
```

...but it will not be clickable.

Anyone get around this without changing underlying HTML?

*Edit: I am using chrome 13.0.782.107. It turns out it's a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92917). (Thanks Sean)*

Comment: it looks like you have discovered a bug in Chrome (I've updated my answer with a workaround).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like you have discovered a bug in the browser you are using.

Based on the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content), the generated content should be treated as a *child* of the element it is being generated for.  I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zx6Wv/23/) to test this out, and the generated text is linked for me in most browsers (Chrome 13 being the solitary exception.)  My guess is that you are testing in Chrome.  This is a reproducible bug.

The workaround is to simply specify a background color on your links ... if you want to be able to use this for all links, declaring a background image (but not specifying an image, or using a transparent `.gif` - or as just pointed out, setting `opacity` to anything other than 1) [works](http://jsfiddle.net/zx6Wv/12/).

Comment: Using `<a class="plain"` in the generated content, and adding `A.plain:before { content: "" }` would avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: @noa -- `:after` ... but good idea :-)  Unfortunately, HTML isn't supported in the generated content (tests here: http://jsfiddle.net/zx6Wv/)

Comment: Very nice. Good catch! I suppose this means I should file a bug against chrome 13 (unless you'd like to).

Comment: @Catskul - just filed one :-)  Thanks though!  (Link is http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92917 if you want to add to it).

Comment: This bug hasn't been fixed yet, as of August 2012.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - this may be a regression - I'd star the bug report, add a comment, and / or open another one against Chrome 21.

Comment: Its finaly fixed in Chrome 71, at this time beta!

Answer (score 4):

If you have a link on Wrapper  then you can make pseudo-elements clickable by setting `pointer-events` to none.

```
a:after {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem and apparently if I set

```
a { vertical-align: middle; }
```

(thus on the link itself, *not* the pseudo element), it works.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your css:

```
a {padding-right:Ypx} /* Y = size of your url in pixels */
```

If the size of the URL varies you will have to use javascript to get it.

Comment: I was just typing up a similar answer when you submitted this. Will this work though? padding will push the after element out as well no?

Comment: @cat no because [generated content does not alter the document tree](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content).

Answer (score 2):

I'm hoping someone has a better solution than this, but just in case not, I did come up with this horrible/crappy/hacky solution:

```
  a {
     margin-right: 40px;
  }

  a:after {
     content: " (" attr(href) ")";
     margin-left: -40px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>To avoid modifying the document tree, you could use a JavaScript click handler for `a:after`.</strike>

**Edit:** This doesn't work, because pseudo elements aren't added to the DOM.

Comment: Are you sure? Could you please post a working example? I don't think there is a way how to attach event listener to a pseudoelement.

Comment: Generated content isn't inserted into the DOM, so JavaScript has no access to its properties/events/methods...

Answer (score 0):

The :before and :after add content *before* and *after* the selector. In CSS, there's no selector that let's you get and edit the content inside a tag. The only way to make that happen would be with jQuery or javascript to actually edit the HTML.

Comment: Not entirely true ... see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content for the specs on how CSS should be able to interact with the attributes of HTML tags defined as the subject of the selector in question.

Comment: "jQuery or javascript" this is a new trend jQuery ≠ javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the link and the text separately -- the :before goes on the container and the link goes inside. This way I can use the :before as a jQuery tigger and the text as a link. 
HTML:

```
<li class="before-here"><a href="#">My Link Text</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
li.before-here:before{ //some css like an image }
```

Jquery:

```
$("li.before-here").click(function(){ //do something});
```

I'm using this to create a hide/show toggle in a tree -- this gives me the button I need on the left and allows me to link to the parent.

[image: open toggle with link]

[image: closed toggle with link]