# Why is this pseudo element not clickable in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have encountered a problem today which only affects Google Chrome. I've not noticed it before when developing and testing a feature a few months back, so I think it might be a new bug.

In the code below, clicking on the blue box does not activate the checkbox. If the label has a display value of `inline-block` and/or the margins are removed, it works. Why?

```css
label {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

input+label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input:checked+label:before {
  content: 'X';
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a">
<label for="a">Label text</label>
```

Edit: I am using Google Chrome version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit).

The linked question was asked in 2011 and was apparently a bug. However it's 2019 and this did used to work until recently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to make a:after/before pseudo elements clickable as part of the link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068091/possible-to-make-aafter-before-pseudo-elements-clickable-as-part-of-the-link)

Comment: It's a Chrome bug. But it's already fixed in v75.

Comment: @Justinas I read this, but in my case it was working and now isn't.

Comment: Get rid of the negative z-index. Problem goes away.

Comment: @j08691 it has nothing to do with the actual real checkbox. Remove all of the CSS for the input element and you will see the issue still exists. The reason you see the problem going away is you are hitting the visually hidden checkbox and not the pseudo element in the label.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Yes read my edit as to why

Comment: I don't see what your edit has to do with my suggestion

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the bug I am demonstrating. Ignore the real input field, remove the CSS for it so it doesn't overlay the pseudo element and sits beside it. The pseudo element when clicked should toggle the checkbox but it does not.

Comment: @Alohci Do you have a link to hand describing the bug? I did look on the issue tracker but didn't see anything I thought relevant.