# Odd scenario / hide names from Google crawlers

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers

My client has a blog and wants to hide all mentioned names from Google's crawlers. For this reason he wrote all personal names l.i.k.e t.h.i.s., seperating each letter with a dot. This approach seems to work, but as I am rebuilding his site right now I am looking for ways that still work, but look less shit and are readable. The dotted pattern is easily replaceable with regEx and I have no problem stripping the dots with PHP, but my question is, what should I replace them to?

- I thought about tags l<em>.</em>i<em>.</em>k<em>.</em>e s<em>.</em>o, so the dots could be hidden via CSS but wouldn't those tags just be stripped by crawlers, leaving the names loud and clear?
- What about leaving the dots in the source but stripping them by JS? Would crawlers see the result or the source?
- Anything else I haven't thought about?

Thanks for hints and ideas!

Comment: 2. Crawlers see the result: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/javascript/javascript-seo-basics .

Comment: That said. You could do the names as `<a>`. And put a `rel="nofollow"` at the `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks @deEr, would this really hide the link text though? I thought the nofollow just meant it wouldn't follow the link, it stopping the indexing of the linked word would seem odd

Comment: To make it complicated. Set the name as `href`. Then do a `rel="nofollow"`. And try with `CSS` like `[href]::before` to show it. Google will obey the rule. But others? 

Comment: To get the `href` as `content` https://stackoverflow.com/q/7068091/2569323 .

Comment: Okay cool, I get it. That seems like the best approach so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you write into the page from a JavaScript file that is blocked from crawling with `robots.txt` won't get indexed by search engines.

#### `file.html`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<script src=/write_name.js>
</head><body>
Your name is <div id=name1></div>
</body></html>
```

#### `write_name.js`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    document.getElementById('name1').innerText = "John Doe"
})
```

#### `robots.txt`

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /write_name.js
```

See [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

Comment: Nice! So that means if I regex remove the dots from n.a.m.e.s with a script blocked by robots.txt, the crawler will see the dotted version?

Comment: Yes, if you disallow the Javascript that alters the page, Google won't see the alterations.